# how to get every value of the table?

Tags: sqlite

So I was trying to check which player owns all the icons and since there are 3 icons the query becomes:

```
SELECT PlayerID from OwnedIcon GROUP BY PlayerID HAVING COUNT(IconID)=3;
```

But what if I don't want it in numbers so if I want to add icons later the query won't change? I tried this but seems like it's dead wrong:

```
SELECT PlayerID from OwnedIcon GROUP BY PlayerID HAVING COUNT(IconID)= SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Icon;
```

Is there any way to change it or do I have to stick with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PlayerID 
from OwnedIcon 
GROUP BY PlayerID 
HAVING COUNT(distinct IconID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Icon)
```

Comment: What happens with distinct IconID?

Comment: That is just if a player could have the same Icon twice. It depends on your logic if that is possible. If not remove the `distinct`